# Hibernate mapping of two classes to a single row in a table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map two classes into single row in a table in Hibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
private int studentId;
private String studentName;

public Student() {
}
public int getStudentId() {
    return this.studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return this.studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}
}
```

and :

```
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

private String street;
private String city;

public Address() {
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

I would like to create a table :

```
CREATE TABLE  "STUDENT" 
("STUDENTID" NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
"STUDENTNAME" VARCHAR2(250), 
"STREET" VARCHAR2(250), 
"CITY" VARCHAR2(250)
)
```

and map STUDENTID and STUDENTNAME from STUDENT class and STREET and CITY from the ADDRESS class.

Mappings I have done currently is the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.vaannila.student.Address" table="STUDENT">
<id>
<generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="street" column="SREET" type="string" length="250"/>
<property name="city" column="CITY" type="string" length="250"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.vaannila.student.Student" table="STUDENT">
<id name="studentId" column="STUDENTID" type="int"/>
<property name="studentName" column="STUDENTNAME" type="string" length="250"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am getting error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/vaannila/student/Address.hbm.xml
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: must specify an identifier type: com.vaannila.student.Address
```

Please help

Comment: hibernate try with annotations, its much more simpler than this...

Comment: annotations are more tightly coupled right? That is why i thought of using mapping.xml files. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user864624 : yes, having configuration in xml makes hibernate application less coupled as compared to having configuration as annotations. Example, a change in column name is easier done in xml than in java file as annotation. The java file needs to be re-compiled to have the change.

Comment: But the development time is much more higher than annotations. And using annotations coding is more simple and all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design, from both a Java object and database entity point of view. Look at your address configuration file - I think you can see where it falls apart, evidenced by your attempt to define an *id* field. Always try and keep in mind what you are trying to model, in this case, *Students* and *Addresses*. If those two entities are always going to be one-to-one then go ahead and consolidate the Address and Student classes (as opposed to trying to split them up).

Of course, I think you will find that the relationship is really Many-to-One. And if we are talking college here than its Very-Many-to-One. The examples on Vaanila are structured that way for a reason, I recommend studying them in detail:

http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-1.html

Comment: I will explain real scenario I am facing. I am hitting a service which will give an xml response which is mapped to jaxb object. This xml has some abbreviations on the top and corresponding expansion in a set of tags at the bottom. I would like to put the abbrv into a table along with the expansion in a row. So i need to map two objects into a same row.

Comment: @sonic - Do you have control over web service and database code? I would recommend having one set of model objects each for your JAXB interaction and DB interaction. You can map multiple JAXB objects onto one DB object.

Comment: I don't have control over what is returned in the service. I have control over the DB code. I have decided to go for a Value Object. map jaxb to VO and put it in DB using hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this pretty easily.  Here is how using annotations from another question:

[Single Table Inheritance WITHOUT Discriminator column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572814/single-table-inheritance-without-discriminator-column)

You will have to figure out the translation to XML on your own if that is desired!

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible you can use **component** tag in xml.